# Angular 2 Routing Guide - Plunker Example not working with IE 11.096 on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

I have been using some of the examples from the Angular router guide (with lazy loading) per the link: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html
I am unable to get the Plunker example to run.  This is the link to my copy of the example:  https://plnkr.co/edit/a4ACZxIxKz0kD2AOZYjL?p=preview.   The only changes I have made have been to add a app/app.component.html file.

Does anyone know if there is a problem with this code?  If so, what needs to be done to make it work?  If the code is fine what could I be doing wrong that would not allow me to run the code?  I have run many Plunker examples before.

Once I get this code to work I then want to change it to have components use the templateUrl property so I can demonstrate another problem I am having with routing.

```
Code for the HTML is:
  <h1 class="title">Angular Router</h1>
  <nav>
    <a routerLink="/crisis-center" routerLinkActive="active">Crisis Center</a>
    <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
    <a routerLink="/admin" routerLinkActive="active">Admin</a>
    <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
    <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { popup: ['compose'] } }]">Contact</a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Looks like it's working for me. What exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: When I run or select Preview I only see, "loading...", the application never comes up.  I restarted my computer in case there was something causing the problem.  Still only see loading.  I went to another plunker and it worked fine.  Can you tell me if you did anything else besides select the link at this site?   Is it possible that I have something in my setup preventing this from running?

Comment: I clicked the link you provided. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Comes up just fine for me as well.

Comment: Thanks, Works with Chrome and Firefox. I usually test my own code with both but for some reason did not think that would be an issue with a Plunker.  I was running with IE 11.0.96.  Must be a bug with somewhere.